# Using OutArgument in Definition of another Activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm creating a Workflow that can call a custom activity called post that will do a webrequest and return the response as an xmldoc.  I tried to return dynamic but that didn't work.  I then want to take a specific value in the xml doc and add it into the post dada of the next post call to chain calls together.  What I can't figure out is how to get the response data from the first post into the post data of the second post.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        Variable<XmlDocument> output1 = new Variable<XmlDocument>();

        ActivityBuilder ab1 = new ActivityBuilder();
        ab1.Name = "CustomWorkflow";
        ab1.Implementation = new Sequence
                             {
                                 Activities =
                                 {
                                     new Post()
                                     {
                                         PostData =
                                             "<xml></xml>",
                                         EndPoint =
                                             "www.test.com",
                                         ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                                         Accept = "text/xml",
                                         Headers = "SOAPAction,Test",
                                         Response = new OutArgument<XmlDocument>(output1)
                                     },
                                     new Post()
                                     {
                                         PostData =
                                             "<xml>"+ output1.GetSingleNode("stuff here") "</xml>",
                                         EndPoint =
                                             "www.test.com",
                                         ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                                         Accept = "text/xml",
                                         Headers = "SOAPAction,Test"
                                     }
                                 },
                                 Variables =
                                 {
                                     output1
                                 }
                             };
```

Answer (score 0):

think you are asking:  How do I transfer a value from 1 Activity to another.
If so, there are a couple of ways to do this.

1)
Have a variable at the workflow level that takes the output from your first activity and then pass this variable as an input parameter to the next activity.

2)
Have a variable that is a data structure and pass the structure into all your activities in sequence.  In each activity you can add/edit/delete data in the structure and because a workflow variable is a reference variable then this data is available to the next activity is the sequence once you pass in the data object.
Instead of a variable you can use an Argument if you want to pass initial data into the workflow.  From then on Arguments behaves like Variables